# Partial update of RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change the field with time in my `RecyclerView`. Each individual `ViewHolder` contains a `CardView` and a few more views inside. The only view I want to animate is the one with time. As you can see, there is no animation:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[image: RecyclerView with no animations]

Updating items one by one doesn't help because then the whole `CardView` flashes:

```
int len = adapter.getItemCount();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to get a list of all `ViewHolders` to then update (animate) just that one `TextView` inside each one?

Comment: You need to add item animator

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can notify your `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s observers to issue a partial update of your `RecyclerView.ViewHolders` by passing a payload `Object`.

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount, payload);
```

Where `payload` could be or contain a flag that represents relative or absolute time. To bind the `payload` to your view holders, override the following `onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position, payloads)` method in your adapter, and check the `payloads` parameter for data.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
        // Perform a full update
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position);
    } else {
        // Perform a partial update
        for (Object payload : payloads) {
            if (payload instanceof TimeFormatPayload) {
                viewHolder.bindTimePayload((TimeFormatPayload) payload);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within your `MyViewHolder.bindTimePayload(payload)` method, update your time `TextViews` to the time format specified in the `payload`.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you very much.

Comment: Brother you saved the day, worked like a charm, I was about to change the recycler view to viewpager. But you answer also made me learn as well as saved my lots of hours of hardwork

Comment: Thank you Ryan . Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38796098/3904109 for a good explanation and working example.