# How to notify adapter of a specific view change instead of an entire ViewHolder change?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, notifydatasetchanged

I have the following code -

```kotlin
dashboardViewModel.getChatReadersForMessageId(it.messageId).observe(this@ConversationActivity, Observer { readersCount ->
   if (readersCount == groupMembers.size) {
       it.messageWasReadByAllMembers = true
       conversationAdapter.notifyItemChanged(messagesList.indexOf(it))
   }
})
```

The issue is that `messageWasReadByAllMembers` effects a single ImageView inside the viewholder, causing an unnecessary re-rendering of the entire VH rather then that single imageview

How do I re-render only specific elements?

Comment: Prefer using ArrayAdapter with DiffUtil, It will have a default implementation of handling what you need. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil

Comment: Add a payload to `notifyItemChanged` and consume it on `onBindViewHolder` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956643/partial-update-of-recyclerview-viewholder/36957892#36957892