# Why Glide blink the item ImageView when notifydatasetchanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, android-glide, blink

I am using [Glide 3.7.0](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) with `RecyclerView`. The item view always blinks when refreshing (calling `notifyDataSetChanged`).

Here is my code:

```
Glide
  .with(context)
  .load(filepath)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
  .skipMemoryCache(true)
  .dontAnimate()
  .into(imageview);
```

When I use no cache, the `ImageView` has a null Bitmap when `notifyDataSetChanged` method is called and Glide hasn't finished loading the bitmap.

If I use the code below:

```
Glide
  .with(context)
  .load(filepath)
  .dontAnimate()
  .into(imageview);
```

Then the item `ImageView` does not blink anymore (using cache).

I want to update the item view dynamically, so I disable the glide cache.

Are there any solutions to solve this blink bug?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After my many tries, just use SimpleTarget solved my problem
thank you!

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(filepath)
.asBitmap()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.dontAnimate()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap arg0, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                holder.mItemView.setImageBitmap(arg0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: SimpleTarget is now deprecated

Comment: I just tried all solutions, but the only one which works is this answer. Thanks a bunch, you saved my day. And as SimpleTarget is depricated now, you can use CustomTarget

Comment: Use CustomTarget now cause SimpleTarget is deprecated.

Comment: but still not working image is still blinking

Comment: yeah no matter what I do it doesnt work

Comment: not working image is still blinking for me too

Answer (score 5):

Update Glide from version 3 to 4 and `setSupportsChangeAnimations(false)` for *RecyclerView* solved problem for me

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
}
```

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 5):

since `SimpleTarget` is deprecated try this solution:

```
GlideApp.with(SOMETHING)
                                .load("WHAT")
                                .dontAnimate()
                                .let { request ->
                                    if(imageView.drawable != null) {
                                        request.placeholder(imageView.drawable.constantState?.newDrawable()?.mutate())
                                    } else {
                                        request
                                    }
                                }
                                .into(imageView)
```

you can also create nice extension for drawable to make REAL copy:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

fun Drawable.copy() = constantState?.newDrawable()?.mutate()
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved the issue by using defined dimensions on my `imageView`.

```xml
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster_imageview"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="183dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Also don't forget to `setHasStableIds(true);` in your `adapter` and properly override `getItemId()` method.
See: [example how to do it](https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/recyclerviews-views-are-blinking-when-notifydatasetchanged-c7b76d5149a2)

Answer (score 2):

try the below
Glide.with(this).load(photoToLoad.getPath()).placeholder(imageView.getDrawable()).into(imageView);

Answer (score 2):

For those who are working with kotlin and BindAdapter, this worked for me:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl", "error", "placeholder")
fun ImageView.loadImage(imageUrl: String?, error: Drawable, placeholder: Drawable) {

    if (imageUrl.isNullOrBlank()) {
        setImageDrawable(error)
    } else {

        try {
            Glide
            .with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap?>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap,
                    transition: Transition<in Bitmap?>?,
                ) {
                    setImageBitmap(resource)
                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    setImageDrawable(placeholder)
                }

            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            setImageDrawable(placeholder)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers solved my problem, which was all the items in the viewholder blinking on update. In my case I was using

```
notifyItemChanged(Index)
```

If you think about it, it makes sense that the item would blink since I was specifically telling the viewholder to update that item in the list. In my case only one of eight things was actually getting updated in the viewholder, but my code only had one way to `onBindViewHolder`. Well it turns out the RecyclerView.Adapter class has a second `onBindViewHolder` function that allows you to only update part of your viewholder if that's all you need. The signature is

```
onBindViewHolder(holder: CommentViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>)
```

And you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50085835/1762587). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

yourRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32220359)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add `.placeholder()` to Glide builder:

```
            Glide.with(view)
            .load(picture)
            .placeholder(placeholderImg)
            .into(view)
```