# Loading images with glide blinks when calling notifyDatasetChanged listener

Tags: android, android-glide

How to avoid flickering of imageview while using glide and calling notifyDataSetChanged on adapter.

Every time  on pull down refresh all the images will flicker.

```
Glide.(context).load(attachment.get(2).getImageLoadingUrl()).override(destWidth,destheight)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.imageplaceholder) 
        .fallback( R.drawable.noimage )
        .error(R.drawable.noimage)        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
        .skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
         .into(iv) ;
```

Comment: which glide version are you using?

Comment: i am using glide 4.0

Comment: are you using viewholder?

Comment: did you look at this https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2194

Comment: There's no way of helping you if you don't provide your code. People can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: If you done it inside if.. condition then pls. use else.. condition.

Comment: Pls. provide you code for better understanding.

Comment: updated the question with code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Glide blink the item ImageView when notifydatasetchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944860/why-glide-blink-the-item-imageview-when-notifydatasetchanged)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setHasStableIds(true);` in your adapter and properly override `getItemId()` method.
See [link how to do it](https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/recyclerviews-views-are-blinking-when-notifydatasetchanged-c7b76d5149a2)