# RecyclerView list with RecyclerView items : How to refresh a specific item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I am making a list with RecyclerView, let's call it VariationList.
VariationList will contains items (VariationsItem).
VariationsItems will contain a title, and a RecyclerView (VariationsItemsList).

If I click on an item of VariationsItemsList, I want the following VariationsItem to refresh, and eventually add or delete some of their items.

Is there any solution to refresh a specific item from the Adapter ?
Or do I need to delete all items, then add them after modification ?

I know it is pretty confusing, so here is an example of my model :

[image]

In red, this is the list of green items.
Each green item contains a title, and a blue list.

For example, if I click on "Petit", I want to refresh the "Test" list.
If I click on "Vert", I want to refresh the "Taille" list and the "Test" list, to eventually add some items, or delete some.

Comment: You don't update the adapter. You update the item, then notify the adapter that an item at a given position has changed.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176336/need-an-example-about-recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemchangedint-position-objec/38796098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in onBindView holder in recycle view adapter

```
    `` @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, final int position) {


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    //code what ever you want to change use position
        }
    });



    });
```

or you can use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for change any item from outside of activity