# why use areItemsTheSame with areContentsTheSame at diffutil recyclerview?

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, compare, android-diffutils

why need to use `areItemsTheSame` with `areContentsTheSame` at diffutil recyclerview?
i don't understand i think areItemsTheSame is enough to compare data?
is possible more explain to me?
thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As short as possible:

`areItemsTheSame` - used to determine structural changes between old and new list (additions/removals/position changes)

`areContentsTheSame` - determines if particular item was updated

---

If objects in your list are immutable you might not have noticed the difference and might as well always return `true` from `areContentsTheSame` but it does matter when your items can be updated.

[DiffUtil.ItemCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.ItemCallback) has 3 methods for a reason. Lets assume you're comparing two objects:

```
Movie A rated at 5 stars
Movie A rated at 4 stars
```

When diff is being calculated following calls are made:

1. `areItemsTheSame`: checks if both objects represent the same item (movie A), returns true
2. `areContentsTheSame`: checks if content is the same (star rating), its not - returns false
3. `getChangePayload`: called when `areContentsTheSame` returns false. It's an optional override that can be used to return payload object for a [partial update of a ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176336/need-an-example-about-recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemchangedint-position-objec). In this example it can return `4` (stars).

Comment: thanks for your explanation ,but if my data list doesn't have an id why we need to use 'areItemTheSame' method. assume you're comparing data list like this 'data class(firstname , lastname)' in this example we don't have an id or any unique parameter so how can implement this data list with diffutil?

Comment: @Mehrzad `DiffUtil` is used to calculate differences between lists and only dispatch necessary changes to the adapter. If your items do not have ID or other way to fulfill `areItemsTheSame` contract then running `DiffUtil` is pointless as it won't be able to determine additions/removals/movement.

Answer (score 2):

`areItemsTheSame(T, T)` is called to see if two objects are the same. If not there may be a need to add/delete the item.

`areContentsTheSame` is called **only when** the `areItemsTheSame(T, T)` return true. In this case, the item was available previously, but the content is changed, so the respective change should be displayed.

`getChangePayload (T oldItem, T newItem)` is called when `areItemsTheSame(T, T)` returns true for two items and `areContentsTheSame(T, T)` returns false for them to get a payload about the change.